# MS Access, modifying combobox data type

Tags: ms-access, combobox

Fairly new to MS Access (been at it for about 6 or 7 months and pretty much self taught, I bow at the alter of Google and Stackoverflow a lot) and am working on a form for a database that is to allow the user to create reports and dictate what they want in the report.

How it's set up is the user has one list that's pre-populated and doesn't change where they select whether the report will show projects that happened during a certain fiscal period, non-project related trips (we'll call them NPTs for now) that happened during a certain fiscal period, or a certain project series.

The **second list** (also prepopulated and unchangeable) only activates if the first or second item in the first list are selected. It allows the user to select the fiscal period and gives the options of either: fiscal year, fiscal quarter, month, or year-on-year comparison.

Once an item in both of those lists are selected it populates the list of one or two comboboxes with options based on what's available in the table that it's pulling from.

The **first combobox** will always be populated and visible, what it's  populated with alters. If the fiscal year, fiscal quarter, month or year-on-year options are selected the first combobox will be populated with the available fiscal years, and if the project series option is selected then it's populated with a list of series names.

There is a second combobox but it isn't relevant to my question so I'll leave details about it out.

My problem comes from the first combobox. Now when you open a new instance of the form no data type is assigned to the combobox but let's say that a user wants to create a report by projects in a fiscal year and he/she selects a fiscal year in the combobox then changes their mind and decides to do a report by project series. When you go to try and select a project series name in the combobox that was populated with fiscal years earlier an error message pops up stating that you're trying to input text into a numeric data type field.

So my question is, is there a way to programmatically change the allowed data type for the first combobox in the AfterUpdate Sub of the first list?

Here's an example of what I have for the first list AfterUpdate Sub (RptByType is the first list):

```
Me.combobox1.RowSource = Switch(RptByType = Project, _
"SELECT DISTINCT Proj.FiscYr FROM Proj ORDER BY Proj.FiscYr DESC;", _
RptByType = Trips, "SELECT DISTINCT NPT.FiscYr FROM NPT ORDER BY NPT.FiscYr DESC;", _
RptByType = Projseries, "SELECT DISTINCT Proj.SeriesNm FROM Proj;")
```

And again FiscYr is in an Integer format, while SeriesNm is in a String format, also combobox1 is not a bound field

Comment: how are you setting the rowsource for the combo-boxes? can you post that code? is your combo-box a bounded field?

Comment: each time you say "list" are you referring to a combobox control?

Comment: no, by "list" I mean a list box. When I refer to combobox, I'm referring to the actual box and the combobox drop-down list all in one

Comment: For now I've just created a separate combobox specifically for the Project Series that's invisible until the Project Series option is selected in the first list box